# excel vba insert row with formatting

Tags: vba, insert, formatting, excel-2007

I have a macro which inserts a number of rows depending on user input in Excel 2007. Everything works but I still have a minor issue. I want to copy the complete formatting from the row above. It only works for some cells in the row.

Here is the code for insertion:

```
 Rows("B:B").Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Is it possible to change it?

best, US

Comment: why don't you copy/paste and then `ClearContents`? Or you could simply Copy/Paste Format (just record a macro and adapt the code)

Comment: Ok. First copied and then inserted it. Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I am not sure exactly how you are inserting your rows, but if you insert the row below an existing one, it will by default take on the formatting of the row above it, at least it does when you use this type of syntax:

```
Range("B2").EntireRow.Offset(1, 0).Insert
```

In this example, it will insert a row below B2 and the format (say, B2's row is highlighted yellow) will be yellow as well. It might have to do with the fact that this type of inserting specifies exactly under which row to insert.

Answer (score 1):

For those that don't want to inherit formatting from parent range use `.cells()`.
`.rows(2).insert` will inherit formatting while `.cells(2).insert` will not.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the first comment.

New code:

```
Rows(CStr(InsRowNumber - 1) & ":" & CStr(InsRowNumber - 1)).Copy
Rows(CStr(InsRowNumber) & ":" & CStr(InsRowNumber)).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
```

Comment: I suggest you edit your answer with the code you've used and then accept it after the delay. Thus, the thread will be closed (i.e. answered) and it will help further users who will find this thread >if SO helped you, please help SO.

Comment: Just want to point out that you don't have to reference a row as Rows(CStr(InsRowNumber - 1) & ":" & CStr(InsRowNumber - 1))

You can simply say Rows(InsRowNumber-1).Copy

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim j As Long, r As Range
j = InputBox("type the number of rows to be insered")

Set r = Range("A4")
Do
    Range(r.Offset(1, 0), r.Offset(j, 0)).EntireRow.Insert
    Set r = Cells(r.Row + j + 1, 1)

If r.Offset(1, 0) = "" Then Exit Do Loop
```